# Blocking access to attachments on Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange-server, attachment, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

I need to block access to attachments via the EWS protocol for a specific user (Exchange Server 2010 SP3). I've been Googling all around without finding any clue.

Any idea?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can't block particular operations in EWS you can disable access to protocol using Set-CasMailbox https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn467892(v=exchg.150).aspx you can also block particular User-Agent strings so if you have an unapproved application if you find the User-Agent string being you can block that https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2016/04/06/step-by-step-blocking-outside-apps-from-accessing-exchange-web-services/. The only possible solution for what you want to do would be doing some type of deep packet inspection with a firewall and then blocking the request based on the SOAP message but I've never seen anybody do that.

Comment: Yes that was plan B :), but it seems so dirty that I'm still hoping there is another way round this.